# Unknown type CalledProcessError output

Tags: python, string, subprocess

I am trying to catch error from Windows 10 terminal. And exc.output returns strings like that `'b'\x8d\xa5\xa2\xa5\xe0\xad\xae \xa7\xa0\xa4\xa0\xad\xae \xa8\xac\xef \xaf\xa0\xaf\xaa\xa8.\r\n'`, how can I convert it in human readable string ?

```
import subprocess

def run_cd(args=''):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(['cd', f'{args}'], 
                                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                          shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        print('error catched')
        print(exc.output)
    else:
        return output.decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: What would be a human-readable string here?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, output value

Comment: What? Please be specific. If you assume that those bytes represent text, then `exc.output.decode(encoding)` would give you the `str` you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga,  it doesn't work, i tried.

Comment: **What are you expecting**?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i am expecting the string with error.

Comment: *What error*? Please be *specific*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga error of comand 'cd' execution with wrong argument